# Does fractallity depend on the Riemannian metric?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, fractals, hausdorff-dimension

> **Edit:** According to comment of Andre Henriques we revise the question:
>   In this question a fractal is a metric space whose topological and Hausdorff dimensions are different. So we would like that this possible counter example comes from a Riemannian structure not merely from a metric space view point.

Is there an example of an analytic manifold $M$ with two real analytic Riemanian metrics $g_1,g_2$ such that $M$ has a compact subset which is a fractal set with respect to $g_1$ but is not a fractal set with respect to $g_2$?

Comment: Under any mathematically formal definition of "fractal", I would expect the answer to be "no". But please: do provide a definition of the word "fractal". Without a definition, it is not possible to answer the question, because the terms in the question are not well defined.

Comment: @AndréHenriques  Thanks for your attention to my question. A fractal is a set whose topological dimension is not equal to its Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: @AndréHenriques Now I revise the question.

Comment: @AndréHenriques Why do you expect the answer is "no"?

Comment: I expect the answer to be "no" because Hausdorff dimension is invariant under diffeomorphisms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. Any two Riemannian metrics when restricted to a compact set are bi-Lipschitz equivalent and bi-LIpschitz homeomorphism preserves the Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.